# Rails how to check if bulk create was successful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mysql2

I am working on a rails method where I need to create copies of a resource. I am using dup for that.

Right now I am using save method in saving new copies and saving it in the iteration:

```
(User.leads2deals.emails - [@old_inquiry.to_email]).each do |dealer|
                @inquiry = @old_inquiry.dup
                @inquiry.to_email = dealer          
                @inquiry.senttoall = true

                if !@inquiry.save
                    all_saved = false
                end

end
```

Depending upon the all_saved boolean flag, I am sending the right message to the user as shown:

```
    if all_saved

        @old_inquiry.senttoall = true
        @old_inquiry.save

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to @parent, notice: 'All Leads were successfuly sent!'}
        end
    else
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to @parent, notice: 'There was some problems sending all the leads! Try sending one by one'}
        end
    end
```

My question is I want to use bulk create. Use an array, build objects and finally call create on that array of the object for efficiency.

But I want to check if create fails for any of the objects, in that case, I will change my boolean flag to false and give the user notifications that not all inquiries were saved.

I checked that create or create! does not return true/false. In this case, how can I check if all the objects were successfully created or not?

Comment: I don't think Rails has bulk insert functionality out the box, but there is [this gem](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert) for it. The thing is, if you use this gem, then your bulk create will not go through your model-layer validations, so you'd have to make database-level validations and probably rescue some kind of error to handle the fail case.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
result = Model.create(array)
```

Then to check if everything was created successfully,

```
if result.all?(&:persisted?)
  # successful action
else
  # failed action
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/Examples#import-using-activerecord-models). It supports validations. All you need to do is to check what it returns when a validation fails and build your response based on that.